# Unable to import pandas profiling in kaggle noteook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kaggle, pandas-profiling

I am working in kaggle notebook and wanted to use pandas profiling for EDA but it is giving error. What can be done to use this library in kaggle notebooks?

[image: Error Screenshot 1]
[image: Error Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though [Kaggle comes with pandas-profiling](https://pandas-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/integrations/cloud_services.html?highlight=kaggle#kaggle) as default, I would recommend running this command in a cell to use the latest version of the package: `%pip install -Uqq pandas-profiling[notebook]`